# $location.path(path) vs $location.url(url) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url

I've seen these calls:

```
$location.url('/path/to/something/' + id + '/index');
```

and

```
$location.path('/path/to/something/' + id + '/index');
```

It seems they are doing the same thing.
From documentation I've found that URL is e.g. `/path?a=b#hash`, and path is a part of URL.

Is there any difference which of these **setters** to use (`$location.path` or `$location.url`) in case of the same argument?

Comment: not if you dont use search strings.  They aren't included in `path`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`$location.path` returns the part of the URL after the slash NOT including search string parameters (after the question mark)

`$location.url` returns the entire URL after the slash, including search string parameters.

For example, let's say you have this URL

http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo

`$location.url` returns `/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`

`$location.path` returns `/some/path`

These two functions act as both `setters` and `getters`.

`Url` is basically `Path + search strings`. In your case, there are no search parameters, so both of them will return the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! Please note that I'm asking about setters.

Comment: Since you are using the same setters with no search parameters, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

`$location.path()` allows you to extract out a specific part of your depending on your search string after the slash and excluding the parameters I guess.  And if you don't have a search string then it works the same way as the `$location.url()` method does.

Comment: Thank you! Please note that I'm asking about setters.