# Page not loading when using $location.path in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do load an html page using angularJS.

My HTML page is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TSAPI Profiles list</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .container{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="TSAPIProfiles" ng-controller="TSAPIController">

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p> <h4> TSAPI Profiles </h4> <br><br></p>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered">

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>TSAPIProfile Name</td>
                    <td>ACD#</td>
                    <td>HUB...</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AESServerPrimary</td>
                    <td>NorthACDTSAPI1</td>
                    <td>NorthACD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>North</td>
                    <td>AESNorth1</td>
                    <td>ManualCBSDetails</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="btn-group-justified" >

              <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: 400px;" >
                <button name="savebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
                <button name="resetbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="edit()">Edit</button>
                <button name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>
              </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS file is like:

```
 var app = angular.module('TSAPIProfiles', [])
    app.controller('TSAPIController',['$scope','$location', function ($scope,$location) {
       $scope.add = function () {
        $location.path('TSAPIProfileCreate.html');
        }

    }]);
```

When I click on add button it doesn't load the `TSAPIProfileCreate.html`. I could not able to find the reason.

Comment: Try
 $location.url("your url")

Answer (score 0):

`$location.path('TSAPIProfileCreate.html'); // This is bad`

`$location.path` returns the part of the URL after the slash NOT including search string parameters (after the question mark).

Create View then use `$location.path`.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

```
$location.path('TSAPIProfileCreate');
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633898/location-pathpath-vs-location-urlurl-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow Manikandan answer because it's the right way to do this (or use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)), but if you really want to make a redirection like this, use : `$window.location.href` like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/zy4RrQmgoxO5yBDZPgdj?p=preview)